# How to add user details to firebase auth table?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

In [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)
, you can see there are methods such as `user.getDisplayName()`, or `user.getPhotoUrl()`, But in my table of authenticated users there aren't any of these:

[image]

My question is, are these methods built-in in Firebase, and I need to change my auth code to have these columns in the table? Or, these are only pseudu-code methods that I need to implement by having the rest of the user's details, such as profile image, and name in Firebase Storage and Firebase Database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a nice question. I also had the same question when I was new to `firebase-authentication`. You can not see those columns in that table but still, you are able to store those meta-data to that table(hidden in that table). At first, you have to create a `UserProfileChangeRequest` object and populate it with your data like this :

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName("ADD_A_DISPLAY_NAME_HERE")
            .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("ADD_PROFILE_PHOTO_URL_HERE"))
            .build();
```

Next, update user profile using the same object you populated like this :

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().updateProfile(profileUpdates);
```

Try this and let us know if it worked or not.

Comment: So why not just store the image in Firebase storage, and the user first and last name in the database?

Comment: You can do that. In fact, to store images you must use `Firebase Storage`(or any other cloud storage provider), `photoUri` can only store photo URLs. And for the username, you can do it whichever way you want.